# How to store simple variables in redux 'useStore' and recall in another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm totally new to Redux.

My understanding is that redux acts like a react hook, for state, and that it is globally available.

I think I should be able to do this (in one component):

```
import { useStore } from 'react-redux'; 

function addToStore() { const [user_name, setUser_name] = useStore("jimmy") };
```

And then recall the variable (in another component) like this:

```
import { useStore } from 'react-redux'; 

function getFromStore() { const id = useStore.user_name }
```

However, this obviously doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I've tried reading the documentation, but it is too complicated for me, doesn't deal with just a single variable storage.

Comment: The docs or a tutorial are where I'd start, e.g., the [Getting Started](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) page. It looks like you're trying to use `useStore` like it's `useState`, which isn't what it is.

Comment: Thanks. I did read the docs, just struggling a bit... :-p

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest Answer:**

Turns out this can be done very simply using window.sessionStorage (Mozilla)

So far I've been able to easily store and retrieve variables across the app, without using Redux.

**Best Answer:**

@liambgs recommended React Context. Turns out this is quite a bit simpler than Redux, but offers much more out of the box than sessionStorage.

To implement Context:

1. Requires no new installation
2. Just import { reactContext } from 'react'
3. Create new component: `class UserContextProvider extends Component {}`
4. Wrap all other components in this new component (in `App.js`)
5. Move all user api's into `UserContextProvider` and store data in local state
6. `render() { return ()}` the component with `value={{this.state}}`

This gave all children components access to the UserContext state.

Comment: If those variables change then your react components wont rerender to reflect the new data. Have you looked into react contexts? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Cheers for this. I'm using context now. Find it much simpler than redux (perhaps because it's native React). Far less code, and does what I need.